# Intuition behind FoldPair and SequenceFold?

Tags: functional-style

In trawling through the documentation I've found the functions [FoldPairList](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldPairList.html) and [SequenceFoldList](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceFoldList.html). Examples are given of how to use FoldPairList:

- Partition a list into sublists of different lengths using TakeDrop
- Break an amount of money into bills of given values using QuotientRemainder
- A discrete-time state-space system is represented using a state equation  and output equation. (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation))

and for SequenceFoldList (both using Plus):

- an implementation of the Fibonacci sequence
- Show convergence to the exact solution when increasing the order of extrapolation.

These examples show some utility of these functions, but ultimately are not illuminating.

**I'm looking for intuition behind these potentially useful functions.**

It should be possible to view these functions through the paradigm of functional program (or Category Theory). In particular:

- Are these functions particular types of [Catamorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamorphism)?
- Are these functions related to [Tree-Like Folds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29#Tree-like_folds)?

I'm no expert in any of this stuff. My guess is that these functions are included in Mathematica more as utility functions used internally for implementing other functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Fold[f, u, list]` is `Nest[f, u, n]` with in addition the possibily to inject in `f` a value  from `list` at each iteration.

That is to say, at each iteration, the input of `f` is feed with :

- the preceding output of `f` **exactly**
- a value of `list`.

`FoldPair` is designed to reinject a value that is different from the exact ouput of `f`.

That is to say, at each iteration, the input of `f` is feed with :

- the **first** part of output of `f`. Indeed, the use of `FoldPair` assumes that `f` returns a pair of data.
- a value of `list`.

It is easy to implement `FoldPair` with `Fold`, but the syntax is not straightforward to understand. 
  The problem with `FoldPair` is that it is not very clear too.

```
FoldPair[{p[#1, #2], q[#1, #2]} &, u, {1, 2, 3, 4}]
```

> p[q[q[q[u, 1], 2], 3], 4]

`FoldPair` implemented with `Fold`:

```
First @ Fold[{p[#1[[1]], #2], q[#1[[1]], #2]} &, {u,}, {1, 2, 3, 4}]
```

> p[q[q[q[u, 1], 2], 3], 4]

That's the main ideas. The rest is a matter of ordering and desencapsulation of a pair of data in a `List` (choice beetween `f[#1,#2] @@ {data1,data2}` or `f[#[[1]],#[[2]]] @ {data1,data2}`.

`FoldPairList` is the list of the successives outputs that `FoldPair` would give for each sublist.

Comment: Thanks for that. You explanation "FoldPair is designed to reinject a value that is different from the exact output of f." seems to align most with the "state space" paradigm above. I'm still struggling to understand this function.

Answer (score 7):

**`FoldPair` is a special case of `FoldPairList` that discards all but the last element**, so we should first create intuition for `FoldPairList`.

## Understanding `FoldPairList`

`FoldPairList` either "slices off from" or "builds up" an intermediate result. I will use an example from the v12.0 documentation to illustrate each paradigm.

### "Slicing off"

> Break an amount of money into bills of given values:
>
> ```
> FoldPairList[QuotientRemainder, 498, {100, 50, 20, 5, 1}]
> (* {4, 1, 2, 1, 3} *)
> ```

`QuotientRemainder` is equivalent to `{Quotient@##, Remainder@##}&`. Here, `FoldPairList` outputs the `Quotient` at each step, passing the `Remainder` to the next value of `f`. Generalizing:

In `FoldPairList[f, y0, {a1, ..., an}]`,

- `f` is of the form `{result[#,#2], remainder[#,#2]}&`, where `result` and `remainder` are two closely related functions.
- At each iteration, `f` uses an element `ai` to "slice off" a `result` and passes the `remainder` to the next iteration.
- `FoldPairList` returns all of the slices.
- `FoldList` returns the `remainder` after taking each slice.
- `FoldPair` returns the last slice (it's rare that you need just this).
- `Fold` returns the scraps left after the last slice is taken.

### "Building up"

> For each element of a list, return True if it is larger than all previous ones, and False otherwise:
>
> ```
> FoldPairList[{#2 > #1, Max[#1, #2]} &, {1, 1, 2, 5, 2, 2, 9, 1, 2, 11}]
> (* {False, True, True, False, False, True, False, False, True} *)
> ```

At each step, `FoldPairList` outputs whether `#2` is greater than the accumulator, and sets the accumulator to `Max[accumulator, #2]`. Generalizing:

- `f` is of the form `{result[#,#2], combine[#, #2]}`.
- At each iteration, `f` outputs some `result`, and `combine`s an element `ai` into the accumulator.
- `FoldPairList` returns all of the outputs.
- `FoldList` returns each value of the accumulator.
- `FoldPair`returns the last output.
- `Fold` returns the final value of the accumulator.

## Examples

[Almost every use of `FoldPairList` I could find](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=foldpairlist) follows either the "slicing off" pattern or the "building up" pattern.

- With `TakeDrop` (a common idiom before `TakeList` was introduced)

  - Slice off `Take[#,#2]`, the first `#2` elements of a list.
  - Keep `Drop[#,#2]`, the rest of the list.
- [With `pickPair`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156447/61597)

> pickPair does the following.
>
> 1. Removes the restricted value from the sample space.
> 2. Converts the sample space such any remaining items will not be picked twice.

- [With `{f[#2] - Count[#, #2], Append[#, #2]} &`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175497/61597)

  - Output `f[#2] - Count[#,#2]`, the adjusted count of a variable `#2` in an expression.
  - "Build up" the expression by appending `#2`.
- [With `{Abs@Total[#2 - #1], #2} &`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/153323/61597):

  - Output the diagonal distance between a point and the accumulator.
  - Set the accumulator to the next point.
  - This does not use the full power of `FoldPairList`, and so can be written as `BlockMap[...,2]` in modern Mathematica.
- Say you earn a certain income and pay federal, state, and local tax in that order, by some function `f[remainingIncome, taxRate]`.

  - `FoldPairList[{f@##, #2-f@##}&, grossIncome, taxRates]` is how much you owe in each tax.
  - `FoldList[#2-f@##&, grossIncome, taxRates]` is your remaining income after each tax is applied.
  - `FoldPair[{f@##, #2-f@##}&, grossIncome, taxRates]` is you how much you owe in local tax.
  - `Fold[#2-f@##&, grossIncome, taxRates]` is your net income.

## Conclusions

It is not surprising that `FoldPairList` is mysterious to many people. We usually think of `Fold` in the "building up" paradigm, whereas `FoldPairList` is most often useful in the "slicing off" paradigm.

`FoldPair` is even more obscure since one typically does not need the last result by itself in either the "building up" or "slicing off" paradigm. Constructing a use case always seems contrived. For this reason, it seems `FoldPair` exists mainly as a companion to `FoldPairList`, `FoldList`, and `Fold`, rather than being useful in itself.

Comment: Very nice explanation, for me the slicing off paradigm is  easier to see when including `Identity` as an extra function in the last argument. For example `FoldPairList[QuotientRemainder, 498, {100, 50, 20, 5, 1}, Identity]` as one can explicitly see the series of evaluations being done. In other words, we can tell a story from the output. That does not work with the building up idea though