# RegionMeasure is wrong for simple 1D Path

Tags: bugs, regions, computational-geometry

**Bug introduced in 11.1**

---

Take the simple path defined by a line through a set of points

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {0, 1.5}, {0.05, 1.5}, {0.05, 0.5}, {0.1, 0.5}, {0.1,  1.5},
{0.15, 1.5}, {0.15, 0.5}, {0.2, 0.5}, {0.2, 1.5}, {0.25, 1.5}, {0.25, 0.5},
{0.3, 0.5}, {0.3, 1.5}, {0.35, 1.5}, {0.35, 0}}

reg = Line[pts];
```

This can be visualized using `Graphics`

```
Graphics[{Blue, reg}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Both `RegionMeasure` and `ArcLength` should give us the length of the line and in fact it does give us a number

```
RegionMeasure@reg
(* 7.85 *)
ArcLength@reg
(* 7.85 *)
```

**This is wrong however!**

This gives the sequence of the individual arc lengths:

```
FoldPairList[{Abs@Total[#2 - #1], #2} &, {0, 0}, pts]
(* {0., 1.5, 0.05, 1., 0.05, 1., 0.05, 1., 0.05, 1., 0.05, 1., 0.05, 1., 0.05, 1.5} *)
```

The sum of this sequence is $9.35$ not $7.85$.

**Sanity check:** Count the line segments on screen. There are two segments of length $1.5$, seven segments of length $0.05$, and six segments of length $1$. So in total: $2\times1.5 + 7\times0.05 + 6\times1 = 9.35$

---

I use **Mathematica 11.1.1.0** on **Mac OS 10.12.6**

---

### Edit in response to comments:

When I copy and paste `pts` from SE I also get $9.35$. Try the following which I used to generate `pts` in the first place:

```
pts2 = AnglePath[{{1.5, 90.°}, {0.05, -90.°}, {1, -90.°}, {0.05, 90.°}, {1, 90.°},
{0.05, -90.°}, {1, -90.°},{0.05, 90.°}, {1, 90.°}, {0.05, -90.°}, {1, -90.°},
{0.05, 90.°}, {1, 90.°}, {0.05, -90.°}, {1.5, -90.°}}] //Chop
```

and check that `pts` and `pts2` are in fact equal

```
pts == pts2
(* True *)
```

Now try `RegionMeasure@Line@pts2`. For me this gives $7.85$. Seems the culprit is `AnglePath`.

Comment: When you suspect a bug, always tell us the version. In 11.1.1 I get 9.35.

Comment: I entered the commands from your post in the same order as you showed them, and got 9.35 with M11.1.1 on OS X 10.12.6 as well.

Comment: Correct answers on 10.3 win

Comment: @Szabolcs See me edit.

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce it. Neither of those lists, or their sublists, are packed, so that is not what is causing them to be different.

Comment: It has to do with the specific numerical values somehow.  For example, `diff = pts-pts2`, then `ArcLength@Line[pts]` is correct and `ArcLength@Line[pts + diff]` is not, even though `Chop[diff]` is all zeros.

Comment: In 10.4 under Linux - everything ok; however, in 11.1 (under Linux) `RegionMeasure@Line@pts2` gives indeed 7.85. `ArcLength@Line[Chop[pts + diff]]` gives 7.85 (in 11.1) but `ArcLength@Line[pts + Chop@diff]` gives 9.35; `diff` are not exactly zeros, but are off by `10^-16`. There are no problems with the `diff` approach in v10.4, however. Another bug in version 11 - that's why I'm still using v10.4.

Comment: Can you report this to Wolfram please?  11.0.1 does not have the problem.

Comment: @Szabolcs I reported this to Wolfram with a link to this discussion.

Comment: The problem indeed lies with the processing of polylines. `ArcLength[RegionUnion[Line /@ Partition[pts, 2, 1]]]` gives the correct answer on 11.1.

Comment: Filed a bug report, thanks for the example. The difference between `pts` and `pts2` is because only 6 digits are printed by default, see `InputForm[pts2]`.

Answer (score 13):

The problem seems to arise from a bug in `` Region`DisjointSegments ``, which drops segments. I don't understand how it works, but I thought it probably has to do with rounding error and might depend on the precision of the points.  Also, translating the coordinates away from `0` should help, which it does. It interesting that the distance translated the points affects discontinuously which segments are dropped.  Perhaps the most disturbing occurrence is the rare result shown below:

```
Manipulate[
 With[{p = SetPrecision[t + pts2, ReleaseHold@prec]},
  foo = Select[Region`DisjointSegments[Line[p]],
    Min[Abs@Differences@#, Infinity] > 10^-8 &];
  If[Length@foo != 0, Print[t -> foo]];
  Graphics[
   {Line[p],
    Red, Thickness[0.02], Line@Region`DisjointSegments[Line[p]]},
   PlotRange -> {{t - 0.02, t + 0.4}, {t - 0.05, t + 1.55}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1,
   PlotLabel -> {t, RegionMeasure@Line[p]}
   ]],
 {{t, -0.09999999999999998`}, -0.6, 0.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {prec, {MachinePrecision, HoldForm@$MachinePrecision, HoldForm[$MachinePrecision + 1]}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It turns out that `` Region`DisjointSegments `` promotes `MachinePrecision` coordinates to the arbitrary precision `$MachinePrecision`.  Setting `prec` to `$MachinePrecision` seems to have no effect.  Bumping it up by `1` more seems to fix the bug.  (In V11.0, promotion to `$MachinePrecision` was also used, so it is not the change that introduced the bug.)