# List manipulation with random elements under limiting conditions

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a function `f1` that should output indexed sublist number in position 1, along with 2 other random choices from the initial list. The sublists must also not contain the same element more than once, and when flattened and sorted, should contain each member of the initial list 3 times exactly:

```
f1[l_List] := Flatten /@ Thread[{l, Partition[
  RandomSample[Flatten[Thread@Array[l &, 2], 1], 2*Length@l], 2]}];
f2[l_List] := With[{li = f1@l},
  {Tr[Length@DeleteDuplicates[#] & /@ li] == 3*Length@l, li}];
```

which I can force to work as desired with something like:

```
f3[l_List] := First[Select[f2[l] & /@ Range@Floor[Length@l^2], #[[1]] == True &]][[2]];
```

*eg*

```
f2[Range@4]
f2[Range@4]
```

might output

```
{False, {{1, 4, 1}, {2, 1, 3}, {3, 4, 2}, {4, 3, 2}}}
{True, {{1, 4, 2}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 1, 2}, {4, 3, 1}}}
```

where part 2 of output 2 is desired output, whereas `f3[Range@4]` usually outputs as desired:

```
{{1, 4, 2}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 1, 2}, {4, 3, 1}}
```

Basically, I need the output for both of the following tests to output sublists of length 3:

```
m = f1@Range@4;
Split@Sort@Flatten@m
DeleteDuplicates /@ m
```

the following output shows then that `m` in this case is not as desired:

```
{{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4}}
{{1, 2}, {2, 1, 4}, {3, 4}, {4, 3, 1}}
```

I have tried approaching this with `NestWhileList`, but have come up short. But is there a better way?

Comment: I think one possible way to do this is to generate derangements of the list (using something like [this](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2002/Oct/msg00555.html)) until you find two that have no overlap. After that, it's just a simple matter of combining all three lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`FoldPairList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldPairList.html) to return a sampled without replacement of the sample space as you progress through the list.

```
ClearAll[pickPair];
pickPair[sp_, val_] :=
 With[{pair =
    RandomSample[ Rule @@ Through@{Values, Keys}@Counts@DeleteCases[val]@sp, 2]},
  {
   Flatten@{val, pair},
   Delete[sp, FirstPosition[#]@sp& /@ pair]
   }
  ]
```

With `list` converted into the sample space `s`.

```
list = Range@4;
s = Flatten[Thread@Array[list &, 2], 1];
```

Then

```
SeedRandom[125]
pickPair[s, 1]
```

> ```
> {{1, 4, 2}, {1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4}}
> ```

`pickPair` does the following.

1. Removes the restricted value from the sample space.
2. Converts the sample space such any remaining items will not be picked twice.
3. Retains the probability density of each remaining item as in the sample space.

The requested index and its pair is returned alongside the remaining items in the sample space.

`pickPair` can be used with `FoldPairList` to obtain the list of indices and pairs.

```
FoldPairList[pickPair, s, list]
```

> ```
> {{1, 4, 3}, {2, 1, 3}, {3, 4, 2}, {4, 1, 2}}
> ```

**However**, this result is a little unstable because it can, on occasion, run out of viable items for the last pair.  For example if it selects `{{1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 4}, {3, 2, 1}}` for positions 1 through 3 then the remaining sample space is `{3, 4}` for position 4. This is not valid since `4` will be removed for position 4.

The good news is that the specification of [`RandomSample`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomSample.html) in `pickPair` will fail in such cases and this can be used to restart the sample.

```
genSample[list_] :=
 Quiet@Check[
   FoldPairList[pickPair,
    Flatten[Thread@Array[list &, 2], 1],
    list],
   Echo@"restart";
   genSample[list]
   ]
```

`genSample` applies this logic of recursive restarting in the event that the sample experiences this issue.

```
SeedRandom[524]
genSample@list
```

> » restart
>
> » restart
>
> » restart
>
> ```
> {{1,4,2},{2,1,3},{3,2,4},{4,3,1}}
> ```

The [`Echo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Echo.html) can be removed as it is only there to demonstrate the restarts.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is great! Thanks - has no problems with lists $\approx |10^4|$ - very helpful indeed - really nice explanation of resampling method too - thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting problem, which I think deserves more than one vote. I took the liberty of generalising it to `n` by `m` matrices, where `n > 1` (in your example `n = 4`) and `1 < m <= n` (in your example `m = 3`). I also wanted to get an algorithm that couldn't go wrong and need to backtrack or start over.

**The function**

The function `generatematrix` takes as arguments `n` (the length of `list = Range[n]`) and `m` (the number of columns in the output matrix).

The basic concept is to create the output matrix row by row, while keeping track of how many more of each number are yet to be placed (in the imaginatively named `yettoplace` variable) and how many available positions there are (in the `availablepos` variable). Some numbers *must* be placed in all rows after a certain point to avoid running out of space.

```
generatematrix[n_, m_] := Module[{
   yettoplace = ConstantArray[m - 1, n],
   availablepos = ConstantArray[n - 1, n],
   unfinished = Range[n],
   mustplace, placeinrow},

  SortBy[Table[
    mustplace = 
     Select[unfinished, 
      availablepos[[#]] - yettoplace[[#]] == 0 && # != i &];
    placeinrow = RandomSample[
      Join[mustplace,
       RandomSample[
        Select[unfinished, # != i && ! MemberQ[mustplace, #] &], 
        m - 1 - Length[mustplace]]
       ], m - 1];
    yettoplace[[placeinrow]]--;
    unfinished = Select[unfinished, yettoplace[[#]] > 0 &];
    availablepos[[unfinished]]--;
    availablepos[[i]]++;
    Join[{i}, placeinrow],
    {i, RandomSample[Range[n], n]}], First]
  ]
```

This is clearly not optimized for speed and/or golfed, but its memory footprint seems pretty minimal for large lists.

**Examples**

To check that the returned matrices are valid (according to the criteria in the question) define

```
validate[matrix_] := 
 With[{n = Length[matrix], m = Length[matrix[[1]]]}, 
  Length /@ Split@Sort@Flatten@matrix == 
   Length /@ DeleteDuplicates /@ matrix == ConstantArray[m, n]]
```

Then

```
mat = generatematrix[4, 3]
validate[mat]

(* {{1, 3, 2},
    {2, 4, 1},
    {3, 4, 1},
    {4, 2, 3}} 

True *)
```

or

```
mat = generatematrix[9, 9]
validate[mat]

(* {{1, 7, 4, 9, 8, 2, 5, 3, 6}, 
    {2, 4, 6, 5, 9, 3, 7, 1, 8}, 
    {3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 9, 1, 4}, 
    {4, 2, 6, 3, 1, 5, 9, 7, 8}, 
    {5, 8, 9, 2, 3, 6, 4, 7, 1}, 
    {6, 7, 4, 5, 1, 8, 3, 2, 9}, 
    {7, 2, 6, 3, 8, 5, 9, 1, 4}, 
    {8, 7, 4, 1, 5, 3, 2, 9, 6}, 
    {9, 5, 3, 2, 6, 4, 1, 7, 8}}

True *)
```

To illustrate its robustness, try it on 10,000 random integer pairs `{n, m}`.

```
nmlist = {#, RandomInteger[{2, #}]} & /@ RandomInteger[{2, 10}, 10000];
And @@ validate /@ (generatematrix @@@ nmlist)

(* True *)
```

(Of course, this doesn't prove it *can't* fail, but I've never seen it do so and suspect it can't.)

**Statistics**

The OP doesn't make specify much about the statistical properties of the algorithm, but out of curiosity I wanted to check the distributions of the numbers. Generating 10,000 4 by 3 matrices and plotting the occurrences of each number in each position (other than the first position of each row), it turns out that the distribution is pretty uniform (thanks, in large part, to randomizing the order that the rows are taken in).

```
matrixlist = Table[generatematrix[4, 3], 10000];
counts = Table[
   Count[matrixlist[[;; , i, j]], #] & /@ Range[4], 
 {i, 4}, {j, 2, 3}];
GraphicsRow[
 BarChart3D[counts[[;; , ;; , #]], ChartLayout -> "Grid", 
    ChartLabels -> {Range[4], {2, 3}}, ViewPoint -> {1, -1, 1}, 
    PlotLabel -> ToString[#] <> "s by position"] & /@ Range[4], 
 ImageSize -> 750]
```

[image]