# How to use FoldList / NestList and Pure function for this?

Tags: performance-tuning, iteration, functional-style

```
    (* P1comb = f[P1]; *)
    P1comb = f[P1] - Count[{  }, P1];
    P2comb = f[P2] - Count[{P1}, P2];
    B1comb = f[B1] - Count[{P1, P2}, B1];
    B2comb = f[B2] - Count[{P1, P2, B1}, B2];
    P3comb = f[P3] - Count[{P1, P2, B1, B2}, P3];
    B3comb = f[B3] - Count[{P1, P2, B1, B2, P3}, B3];
```

I am writing the above code, which works perfectly fine. Then I noticed a `pattern`, so I am just wondering if I might be able to write it better (more compactly) and more efficient using something like `FoldList` or `NestList` combined with a pure function, like

```
FoldList/NestList [] & {P1,P2,B1,B2,P3,B3}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might consider using `FoldPairList`:

```
Column[
FoldPairList[{f[#2] - count[#, #2], Append[#, #2]} &, {}, {P1, P2, B1,B2, P3, B3}]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I have replaced `Count` with `count` to display the expression.

It would also commonly be done like this:

```
elems = {P1, P2, B1, B2, P3, B3};
lists = Most@FoldList[Append, {}, elems];
MapThread[f[#] - count[#2, #] &, {elems, lists}] // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for both methods. I'd prefer to use the 1st one as it looks more compact! :)

Comment: Weirdly, after putting it into my `big` function, it used double of the execution time. I think it might be caused by `Append`? But don't worry. That's not really the point here.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that avoids `Append`, but does pre-generate the partial sublists from your list:

```
list = {P1, P2, B1, B2, P3, B3};

f[#1] - Inactive[Count][Reverse[{##2}], #1] & @@@ 
  (Reverse[list[[;; #]]] & /@ Range[Length[list]])

(* Out: 
 {f[P1] - Inactive[Count][{}, P1], 
  f[P2] - Inactive[Count][{P1}, P2], 
  f[B1] - Inactive[Count][{P1, P2}, B1], 
  f[B2] - Inactive[Count][{P1, P2, B1}, B2], 
  f[P3] - Inactive[Count][{P1, P2, B1, B2}, P3], 
  f[B3] - Inactive[Count][{P1, P2, B1, B2, P3}, B3]}
*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course, you should remove the `Inactive` part in your actual code :-)

---

See also [Any built-in function to generate successive sublists from a list?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16556/27951) for alternative ways to generate the initial sublists.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[P1, P2, B1, B2, P3, B3]
Clear[P1comb, P2comb, B1comb, B2comb, P3comb, B3comb]

a = {P1, P2, B1, B2, P3, B3};
b = {P1comb, P2comb, B1comb, B2comb, P3comb, B3comb};
```

Using lower-case `count` initially, to be replaced with `Count`

```
Array[With[{c = b[[#]]},
   c = f[a[[#]]] - count[Take[a, # - 1], a[[#]]]] &, Length[a]]
```

Examples

```
P1comb
```

> ```
> -count[{}, P1] + f[P1]
> ```

```
B3comb
```

> ```
> -count[{P1, P2, B1, B2, P3}, B3] + f[B3]
> ```

Assigning values after symbolic construction.

```
With[{d = a}, d = {1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2}];

B2
```

> ```
> 4
> ```

```
b /. count -> Count
```

> ```
> {f[1], f[2], f[3], f[4], -1 + f[3], -1 + f[2]}
> ```